# Reading batches of data from BigQuery into Datalab

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have a big dataset in BigQuery table (~45M lines, 13Gb of data). I would like to process that data in my Google Datalab Notebook to do some basic statistics with pandas to visualise data later with matplotlib in Datalab cell. I think it is not a good idea to try to load all dataset into pandas' Dataframe (at least I will have RAM issues).

Is it possible to read data from BigQuery in batches (say 10K lines) to consume it in Datalab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your purpose is to visualize the data, would sampling be better than loading a small batch?

You can sample your data such as:

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
df = bq.Query(sql='SELECT image_url, label FROM coast.train WHERE rand() < 0.01').execute().result().to_dataframe()
```

Or, a use convenient class:

```
from google.datalab.ml import BigQueryDataSet
sampled_df = BigQueryDataSet(table='myds.mytable').sample(1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for idea with sampling @BradleyJiang, it could be helpful! But here I'm working with chronological data and subsampling will destroy time-ordered lines.
If I will not find a way for batch reading from BigQuery, I guess I will need go to the original csv file and will read lines in a batch.

Comment: Then how about sorting them by time and then query it by pages?

    import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
    q = bq.Query('select * from myds.mytable order by time')
    t = q.execute().result()
    t.to_dataframe(start_row=page_start, max_rows=page_size)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just iterating over the table? The `Table` object is an iterable that uses a [paged fetcher](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/google/datalab/bigquery/_table.py#L761) to get data from the BigQuery table, it is streaming in a way. The page size is 1024 by default.